# Formulas, Latin with Umlauts, Ancient Greek - Font Recommendations

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, greek

I am currently trying to standerdize all my assignments. So I am looking for a font that is suitable for math formulas and the latin alphabet with diacritics, but also ancient greek (so the polytonic character set). It should obviously be legible on a computer but also legible when printed. (In my opinion computer modern serif looks quite thin when reading it on a computer and very streched out when made bold) Thank you for your help!

Comment: why "a" font?, the math and text fonts are usually specified separately. There are several to choose from hard to tell you which you will prefer. If you font lm a bit thin try the imes cloes such as TeX Gyre Termes for text and TeX Gyre Teres Math for math (if teh Greek coverage is sufficient)

Comment: I should have frased the question differently, because as long as the fonts match it doesn´t make a difference, but with most font comninations I tried, I couldn´t find a great match

Comment: to use a font with unicode math it has to be specifically a math font with an opentype Math table, in all cases I know of these are specifically designed to go with a text font (although other combinations are possible) so latin modern math with latin modern, stix two math with stix two text, tex gyre termes math with tex gyre termes, (there is a conventional pattern in the naming:-)

Comment: And also to add: greek coverage isn´t just for math, but writing in general, as I sometimes have to write in modern and ancient greek

Comment: well that's why I asked about  needing to be a single font as you can match a text font with polytonic Grek with a math font without.

Comment: And I looked in Gyre, but it has catastrophic support for greek

Comment: For text, for "Greek Extended" Unicode codeblock, DejaVu Serif, FreeSerif, Liberation Serif, Noto Serif, Palatino Linotype, have full coverage (233 characters). And many others. Cambria Math on Windows, too.